# Pass an object as parameter from a UserForm to another one

Tags: excel, vba

I create a `Class` type Employee

```
Private emplId   As String
Private name     As String
Private rank     As String
Private post     As String
```

I create a module with a function Inside who return an object type Employee.

```
Public Function FuncNewPerson(Emplid As String) As Employee

Dim newPerson As New Employee

With newPerson
    newPerson.SetEmplid = Emplid
    newPerson.SetName   = mytab(25, 1)
    newPerson.SetRank   = mytab(23, 1)
    newPerson.SetPost   = mytab(27, 1)

Set FuncNewPerson = newPerson
```

I use two `UserForms`, in the first one after selection of an `emplId` via a `ComboBox` it initialize an object type `Employee`, then I fill all the `TextBox` of the first `UserForm` with the `get` property of the object :

```
RequestForm.TxtBoxPerson = person.GetName
RequestForm.txtBoxRank   = person.GetRank
```

On this `UserForm` i have a `Button` who calls the second one :

```
Public Sub BtnVerify_Click()
    Me.Hide
    ValidationForm.Show
End Sub
```

In the second `UserForm` I have some other `TextBox` to fill :

```
ValidationForm.TxtBoxEmployee = person.GetEmplid
ValidationForm.txtBoxRank     = person.GetRank
ValidationForm.txtBoxPost     = person.GetPost
```

I would like to use the object who is already in memory so my first idea is to pass it as an argument from the first form to the second one.

Of course i already searched the web but i'm now more confused about it, that's why i ask some help here in order to :

1. get some clues
2. get a feedback about my way of doing this

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second form, create a suitable variable

```
Private Person as Employee
```

Then create a property

```
Property Set CurrentPerson(p as Employee)
   set person = p
End Property
```

Then set this property in the code from your first form

```
Public Sub BtnVerify_Click()
    Me.Hide
    ValidationForm.Show
    Set validationform.currentperson = person

End Sub
```